# How can I replace every nth empty element in a masked array?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I replace every first empty element after each series of found ones in a masked array. It is a bit hard to explain but the following example illustrate what I would like to do:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,1,1])
Ones = np.ma.masked_where(data > 2, data)

print(Ones)

Output: [1 1 1 -- -- -- 1 1 1 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1 1 1 -- -- 1 -- -- -- -- 1 1 1 -- -- -- 1]
```

I would like to add an additional "1" after each consecutive row of ones so the result would be:

```
[1 1 1 1 -- -- 1 1 1 1 -- -- -- -- -- -- 1 1 1 1 -- 1 1 -- -- -- 1 1 1 1 -- -- 1 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension + "if programming" can make this job inline:

```
data2 = [ 1 if (i>0 and data[i-1]==1 and x!=1) else x for i,x in enumerate(data) ]
```

1st if is for the 1st list element exception.

2nd if to detect if previous element was 1.

3rd if to check if we have some new value to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a way to do this without python loops, and found we can use scipy's ndimage library to dilate our mask:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd

data = np.array([1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,1,1])
mask = np.where(data == 1, data, 0)
# [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]

# 2nd argument lets `binary_dilation` know we only want to expand to the right
expanded_mask = nd.binary_dilation(mask, np.array([0, 1, 1]))  
if mask[-1]:
    expanded_mask = np.r_[expanded_mask, 1]
# [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

The conditional at the end is only if we need to insert one last `1`.